# Suppose $E=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ and the cardinal number of $E$ is $c$.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

> Suppose $E=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ and the cardinal number of $E$ is $c$ ($c$ represents the cardinal number of $(0,1)$). Prove that there exsits $n_0$ such that the cardinal number of $A_{n_0}$ is also $c$.

For now, I have proved if $E=A_1\cup A_2$ the conclusion holds. Then by induction the finite union case is also true. But I do not know how to prove the denumberable case stated above.

Appreciate any help or hint!

Comment: Hint: show that the union won't be countable at a certain index. As an uncountable union  does not produce a countable number.

Comment: Did you secrestly use the continuum hypothesis? Can you be more specific? I don't really follow.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Are you aware that the [cofinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinality) of $\mathfrak{c}$ must be uncountable? This is a corollary of [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)).

Next, if you want to hit $\kappa$ by unioning stuff smaller than $\kappa$, you'll need to union at least $\text{cf}(\kappa)$ many things (do you see why?).

Putting these two facts together: if we try to union up countably many things of size $\lt \mathfrak{c}$, can we hit $\mathfrak{c}$?

As an aside, notice that we *need* choice in order to run this argument. It's consistent without choice that $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: We can apply König's theorem right away: suppose on the contrary that each $A_n$ has smaller cardinality than $c$. Then $$|E|\le\sum_n|A_n|\ <\  c^\omega=(2^\omega)^\omega=2^\omega=c$$